# Echo out rowCount in a div

Tags: php, pdo

Im probaly doing it all wrong, but I cant seem to get it correct...
I have an query that works just fine, Now if i write in the query

```
echo $query->rowCount()
```

;
it gives me the amount of rows on the screen.
But i would be able to insert this echo into a div, So I tried this.

```
function fetch_tweets($uid){ 
$query = $this->link->query
("SELECT.....
WHERE... "); 

$tweet = array();
while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) { 
$tweet[] = $row;
}   
$numrows =  $query->rowCount(); /* Count the messages*/
return $tweet; 
 }
```

And then on the page.

```
  $tweets = new Tweets();   
    $numrows = $tweets->fetch_tweets($_GET['uid']);
    <div> <?php echo $numrows; ?> </div>
```

But it only echos out Array.

Comment: echo count($numrows); //you return $tweet in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `$numrows` to what you return with `fetch_tweets()`. So, that'll be an array of tweets. This is how to show the number of elements in an array:

```
<?php echo count($numrows) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `fetch_tweets` function your returning an array with tweets. The fastest solution for your problem now would be:

```
$tweets  = new Tweets();
$rows    = $tweets->fetch_tweets($_GET['uid']);
$numrows = count($rows);
<div> <?php echo $numrows; ?> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div> <?php echo count($numrows); ?> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are returing an array, so when you print "$numrows" prints you "Array". You should use a "foreach" and get your values from "$numrows".

But if you trying to get the number of rows, you are returing the wrong variable, you are returing "$tweet" and must be "$numrows".

Answer (score 1):

Change your function like this:

```
function fetch_tweets($uid){ 
    $query = $this->link->query ("SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE stuff"); 

    $tweet = array();
    while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) { 
        $tweet[] = $row;
    }

    $tweet["rowcount"] = $query->rowCount(); /* Count the messages*/
    return $tweet; 
}
```

Then in your code just put:

```
$tweets = new Tweets();
$tweet = $tweets->fetch_tweets($_GET['uid']);
<div><?=$tweet["rowcount"]?></div>
```

Make sure to put an IF statement in your loop of tweets to filter out the "rowcount" key value.

Comment: Alternatively you can create a global variable, or class variable, and alter its value instead of adding it to the array like I wrote. Then you can just use the $tweet_rowcount or $tweets->rowcount instead of the array value I listed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it echos "Array" because that's what it is, an array. ;)

Just follow your code:
First you generate your Tweet object. Then you call the `fetch_tweets()` method on that object which returns you an array of stuff from your database and save the result in a `$numrows`. And then you output the variable. But as it's an array, all you get is "Array", and that is the expected behaviour.

If you want the number of rows as returned from `rowCount` you need to either change the return object of the `fetch_tweets()` method and add it. Or, much easier, you could simply use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) on the returned array, as you don't seem to alter the amount of rows returned by your query.

And now to some more general stuff:

- Don't ever use `$_GET`, `$_POST` or any other variable that might contain user-editable data for a query without checking it beforehand.
- Use [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) instead of iterating yourself through the resultset of the query.